# Solve differential equation $ (dy/dx)(x^2) + 2xy = \cos^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(dy/dx)(x^2) + 2xy = \cos^2(x)$

$(dy/dx) + 2y/x = \cos^2 x$

I multiplied both sides by $e^{2\ln\ x + c}$, then rewrote the equation as

$(d/dx)(y* e^{2\ln\ x + c}) = (\cos^2(x)/x^2)*(e^{2\ln\ x + c})$

Now when I try to integrate, the right side becomes complicated. 
Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm following the textbook.

Comment: So it would simplify to: 
yx^2 = integral(cos^2(x) dx) => 
yx^2 = x/2 + 1/2sin(x)cos(x) + c

and then just divide both sides by x^2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side is the derivative of $x^2y$. Let $u=x^2y$. Solving the differential equation $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos^2 x$ is a routine integration.

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding an integrating factor, you can always rescale by a non-zero constant. So instead of selecting $e^{2 \ln x} e^c$, set $c = 0$ to get

$$e^{2 \ln x} = x^2$$

This leads directly to André Nicolas' observation that the left-hand side is the derivative of $x^2 y$.